# Doubt in understanding what is really meant by a vector

Tags: kinematics, vectors

Sorry for asking a very common question. For now this is a question which make me depressed for about an year. As a mathematics student I studied vectors very axiomatically which makes me feel depressed. Now my question is what is a vector .please don't say that vectors are quantities having both magnitude and direction. Please explain that.

What does one mean by the word position vector?
Do the vector position vector and the vector with same magnitude and direction is same?( refer picture)[image]
Do 1 and 2 represent the same vectors?

The vector 2**i**+3**j** is represent by an arrow pointing the point (2,3) in the plane. But how can we represent the vector x**i**+y**j** where x and y are variables.

Please suggest me a good book which has a good approach to vectors from the basic. I want to understand the practical difference between the vectors and the statement "each point in a plane is a vector".

Please help me.

Comment: Your question is about mathematics, not physics.

Comment: OK please tell me the thing that what is a vector in physics.

Comment: Vector is an element of vector space. In your case, the vector is a list of length two, in simplest terms.

Comment: Noooooooo I can't understand. My mind is totally thinking on vectors.

Comment: Vectors in physics are defined in many ways at different levels of mathematical rigor. *"A quantity with both magnitude and direction"* is a first-year definition adequate for teaching Newtonian mechanics. Alas *"a vector is a quantity that transforms like ..."* (many upper division undergrad and grad texts) is both difficult to wrap your intuition around and tightly linked to the use of coordinates. You can avoid that with a really abstract approach in which a vector becomes a map onto a field or some such dense mathematical language but ...

Comment: Ok please suggest me some books @dmckee

Comment: Try googling, or looking in your school library, or asking your teachers. There are plenty of resources on vectors. You are the best person to decide which of them is "good" for you... The best definition in basic physics is a quantity which has magnitude and direction, but you don't like that. In physics your arrows 1 and 2 are the same *direction* vector : they have the same magnitude and the same direction. *Position* vectors always start at the origin. They tell you the *position* relative to the origin.

Comment: Yeah yeah  what does that position vector mean.@sammy gerbil

Comment: Please don't get angry at me

Comment: Sry I'm a college student. Even though  I'm good in analysis, I found difficulty in algebra because I don't know about vector

Comment: This is asking a bunch of different things. I think it needs to be focused on one specific issue to make it an effective question for this site.

Comment: Ooh sure @David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often, when a physicist talks about a vector (particularly in undergraduate university courses), they are referring more specifically to a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. (One can generalize this to an abstract vector space, but for elementary classical mechanics this is unnecessary.) There are two ways of thinking about equality of vectors (in $\mathbb{R}^3)$:

1. Two vectors are equal if they have the same components, or
2. Two vectors are equal if they have the same length (magnitude), and same direction.

These different definitions of equality are *equivalent.*

To some of your more concrete questions.

> What does one mean by the word position vector?

The position vector of a point $P$ in space is a vector $s$ such that if I place the tail of $s$ on the origin, the head (arrow) of $s$ will be on $P$. Every point in 3D space has its own unique position vector and every position vector a unique point, so we can (if we're being casual) say vectors *are* the points on the plane. As you alluded to in your question however, this isn't always the best idea.

> Do 1 and 2 represent the same vectors?

Yes, they have the same direction and same magnitude. If the tail of 2 were placed on the origin, then the heads of 1 and 2 would be on the same point, and thus the vectors are the same.

> But how can we represent the vector $x\mathbf{i}+y\mathbf{j}$ where $x$ and $y$ are variables.

Draw the point $(x,y)$ on the plane and a vector starting at the origin and ending at $(x,y)$. That's a graphical representation of $x\mathbf{i}+y\mathbf{j}$. Another representation is $x\mathbf{i}+y\mathbf{j}$, with respect to the basis $(\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j})$.

Comment: Suppose that a bullet is fired from the tail of the vector 2.Now 2 gives the displacement of the bullet. Even now 1 and 2 represent the same ?@eepperly16

Comment: Call the point at the tail of vector 2 $P$. Vector 2 *is not* the position vector of $P$ because vector 2, if placed at the origin, will not end at $P$. So the initial displacement of the bullet must be given by some other vector.

Comment: Note that in the length-magnitude description you have to make an exception to the equality rule because all zero-length vectors are equal regardless of what direction they are assigned (indeed, direction doesn't make a lot of sense for zero-vectors).